# How to increment date inside an single tab?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am an newbie to android.My task is to create an android app with one tab which swipes to infinite times.My first screen will have to display current date and on forward swipe it should increment to tomorrow's date and so on.I don;t know how to implement it.Please suggest and guide me friends.

Thank you.

My main activity is here

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }



        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return 100;
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                Tab2 tab2=new Tab2();
                return tab2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

                    return "SECTION 3";

        }

    }
}
```

And my fragment activity is here

```
public class Tab2 extends Fragment {
    String strDate;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        for (int i = 0;i<=100;i++) {
                if (i < 1) {
                    try {
                        Date myDate = sdf.parse("15/07/2017");
                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        c.setTime(myDate);
                        c.set(Calendar.DATE, c.get(Calendar.DATE) + 1);
                        Date newDate = c.getTime();
                        strDate = sdf.format(newDate);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
           else {
                    Date day = new Date();
                    strDate = sdf.format(new Date(day.getTime()));
                }
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2,container,false );
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        TextView textView2 =  getView().findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView2.setText(strDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the position of fragment to add day to current date.
The position of first fragment is 0, so add 0 day to date. The second fragment's position is 1, so add 1 day to date and so on..

Here is `Tab2` fragment code:

```
public class Tab2 extends Fragment {
    private int position;


    public Tab2() {
    }

    public static Tab2 newInstance(int position) {
        Tab2 fragment = new Tab2();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            position = getArguments().getInt("position");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_t2, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, position);
        String dt = sdf.format(c.getTime()).toString();


        TextView textView2 =  getView().findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView2.setText(dt);
    }
```

Now in your `SectionPagerAdapter`'s `getItem` method, send `position` to frament:

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return Tab2.newInstance(position);
    }
```